# Camel SOAP CXF Call With Dynamic Addresses

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I'm trying to write a SOAP Web Service that:

1. accepts one request type A
2. maps request A to another outbound request type B
3. sends request B to an external SOAP service
4. maps the response B back to a response A object (and returns it)

I have this working when the endpoint (B) is statically configured.

But I want to be able to hit a variety of services with varying request/response types. These would probably be configured via a properties file.

Is it possible to do this in some generic/dynamic way?

Here's my spring camel XML:

```
<!— SOAP inbound service —>
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="paymentService_A"
        serviceClass="#paymentServiceBean"
        address="/PaymentService"/>

<!— SOAP outbound service —>
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id=“paymentService_B"
        wsdlURL="http://localhost:9080/externalpayment/ExternalPaymentService?wsdl"
        serviceClass="com.yngwietiger.ExternalPayment"
        address="http://localhost:9080/externalpayment/ExternalPaymentService"/>

<!— MAP from inbound SOAP request object to external SOAP request object —>
<bean id="mapAToB_RequestProcessor" class="com.yngwietiger.MyProcessor"/>

<!— MAP external SOAP response to a response for the initial/inbound SOAP request —>
<bean id="mapBToA_ResponseProcessor" class="com.yngwietiger.MyPostProcessor"/>

<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">

    <camel:route>

        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:paymentService_A"/>
        <camel:process ref="mapAToB_RequestProcessor"/>
        <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:paymentService_B"/>
        <camel:process ref="mapBToA_ResponseProcessor"/>

    </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Obviously, I'm using Camel's cxfEndpoint bean. But I don't see any way to set the address, wsdlURL, etc for each request. Is that possible?

Or am I going to have to build a route for each type? If so, how do I build one of these cxfEndpoints dynamically?

Would using Spring's WS Template be more flexible?

Is there a better way that I should be doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Camel Recipient List would better fit into your requirement. This is the link, http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html. You have to generate the dynamic endpoint and set into the header somewhere in the route and call the recipient list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use HTTP endpoint for your outbound message.
As it is done in the example [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html)